# Rails Authentification with Devise: Redirect to Sign-In form after Sign-Up

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, devise, ruby-on-rails-6

I'm building an authentication using Devise.

Creating users works, but after the creation the user is automatically logged-in and becomes redirected to the root-page.

I have created an own RegistrationController and overwritten the after_sign_up_path method:

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
    def after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
        "/users/sign_in"
    end
end
```

But it doesn't work.

**What have I done wrong, respectively what have I missed.**

I have read various other StackOverflow question already. Until now nothing has worked.

Here's my routes.rb too:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :comments
  resources :posts
  devise_for :users, controllers: { registrations: "registrations" }
  root "posts#index"
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the default sign up method that ships with the RegistrationsController

```
  # Signs in a user on sign up. You can overwrite this method in your own
  # RegistrationsController.
  def sign_up(resource_name, resource)
    sign_in(resource_name, resource)
  end
```

You can override it in your code.

Comment: You have to do it the other way around: def sign_up() SIGN_OUT() end

Answer (score 2):

It seems like after you sign up successfully devise automatically log in and you cannot get login page if you still log in, correct me if I'm wrong

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Nick M's answer I could solve the problem the following way:

First make sure your "routes.rb"-file has a line like here ...

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users, :controllers => {:registrations => "registrations"}
  ...
end
```

Then create a "registrations_controller.rb"-file and add there this:

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  protected

  def sign_up(resource_name, resource)
    sign_out :user
  end
end
```

Doing it that way results in being redirected to the Login-form automatically, after creating a user. Exactly the behaviour I liked to accomplish.

"*#sign_out(resource_or_scope = nil) ⇒ Object*

*Sign out a given user or scope. This helper is useful for signing out a user after deleting accounts. Returns true if there was a logout and false if there is no user logged in on the referred scope*

*sign_out :user     # sign_out(scope)
sign_out @user     # sign_out(resource)*"

[Source](https://www.rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/Devise%2FControllers%2FSignInOut:sign_out)